# Can I use EntityGraph to make EAGER association LAZY?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

For example I have

```
class Foo {
  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  Bar bar;
}
```

and in some queries I want not to load bar.

I found the way to solve this:

```
interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
  @EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = "id")
  Optional<Employee> findReducedById(Long id);
}
```

`@EntityGraph(type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH, attributePaths = "id")` - gives what I want, **but it looks like a hack**. `attributePaths = {} or attributePaths = {""} or attributePaths = ""` don't work.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the best way to do it correctly is to use `@NamedEntityGraph`:

```
@NamedEntityGraph(name = Foo.FOO_RESTRICTED, attributeNodes = {})
class Foo {
  ... String FOO_RESTRICTED = "Foo.Restricted";

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
  ... Bar bar;
}
```

and repository:

```
interface FooRepository extends JpaRepository<Foo, Long> {
  @EntityGraph(value = Foo.FOO_RESTRICTED, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.FETCH)
  Optional<Employee> findReducedById(Long id);
}
```